# Communication with OBD-II using Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, bluetooth, serial-port, obd-ii, elm327

I have a problem with sending and receiving data from elm327 device.
I tried to connect to the device using channel 01 (on Bluetooth) but it doesn't matter what command I send, I just receive the string `"AT+BRSF=24\r"` as an answer.
I tried also to connect at channel 16 and there I receive a string `"NO DATA"`

somebody knows what is the problem?
thank you,
Arie

Answer (score 0):

The AT+BRSF=24 response sounds like you're communicating with the wrong Bluetooth device (perhaps a headset?).

"NO DATA" sounds like an ELM327 response. What command are you sending? Try "ATZ\r" to start with.

Comment: No, it was with the obd2 device.
The problem was that I didn't connected with the right channel